# Automatically install pip packages' OS dependencies

Tags: pip, dependency-management

I am installing lots of `pip` packages on a `debootstrap`'d Debian which is understandably quite bare bones and lacks a ton of packages that you'd usually expect on a regular installation. Naturally, `pip` installations are failing because the OS doesn't have the libraries they depend on.

Instead of individually digging for dependencies I need to install, is there a way to let `pip` resolve `apt` dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

No. `pip` is a portable tool designed to be run on many operating systems. But on every operating system `pip` works with just Python packages and doesn't touch system libraries. If you install Python packages with `apt` or any other distribution-specific package manager it handles all dependencies. When you add `pip` to the toolbox — you are on your own.

Comment: I know, I'm looking for either a third-party solution or some way to build something to programmatically figure out what's missing from `pip` output and and fetch  them.